# Is "lie one on" really an American English slang expression for "getting drunk"?

Tags: phrase-meaning

Some time ago I wrote down "lie one on" with this meaning for a flashcard; I must have read it somewhere, probably in a book, but I don't remember where. After a couple of months I wanted to look up the phrase again, but couldn't find it anymore. It doesn't seem to be listed in a single dictionary (also not in my American slang dictionary) and I can't find it on the Web. Does this expression really exist? Unfortunately, because I don't remember where I found it I can't give any context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression is "*tie* (not lie) one on."

Its origins are somewhat disputed, with some claiming that it references a cowboy tying his horse to a hitching post before going into a saloon to get drunk.

Regardless, yes, it is a euphemism for getting drunk or having an alcoholic drink.

Comment: I did find half-a-dozen written instances of [***laid** one on last night*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22laid+one+on+last+night%22) in Google Books. But set against 927 instances of [***tied** one on last night*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22tied+one+on+last+night%22) I'm inclined to think that's just "inaccurate copying", rather than a true "dialectal variation".

Comment: @FumbleFingers _laid one on_ is actually a separate phrase, but it refers to the act of punching, hitting hard, or kissing someone.